# Alternative to constructor for setting Form location?

Tags: c#

I want to set the location of a form using:

```
this.Location = new Point(2908, 953);
```

in the constructor. The constructor seems to ignore it. I want it to go to the location only once during the whole execution of the program and have it do it right when the program starts.

What should I do?

Comment: Set it in the designer?

Comment: C# and what? WinForms? WPF?

Comment: That seems awfully specific. I'd recommend against using hard-coded values like that. What if the user's screen isn't that large?

Comment: I agree with @p.s.w.g, but set the `StartPosition` to `Manual` first for this to work.

Comment: Is it before `InitializeComponents` or after it?

Comment: The hard-coded values are there because I am making a clock for the bottom right corner of my second monitor. I will always have it running, and it will always be in the same corner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to set the initial position of a Form from the constructor you will need to change the `Form.StartPosition` from the default value to `FormStartPosition.Manual`

```
public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
    Location = new Point(2908, 953);
}
```

Although you no longer need an alternative; an alternative to using the constructor could be to change the location of the Form in the `Form.Load` event handler.

Answer (score 1):

Correct way is to use StartPositon property, as pointed out by anonymous user, but I found (hard way) that this works too:

```
IntPtr h = this.Handle; // to make Location=... work
Location = new Point(200,10);
```

Anybody cares to explain why it works? (h is not used anywhere in the constructor, BTW)

Comment: Can confirm this allows manually setting the location in the constructor. It is most likely an implementation quirk.